# Android - can't enable BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, securityexception

I got back to the widget development after upgrading to the latest SDK and all of the sudden my widget is failing on startup with this message:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5296): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start receiver topjob.widget.SearchWidget: 
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
attempt to change component state from pid=5296, uid=10057, package uid=10048
```

Here's two lines of code where exception occurs:

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("topjob",
            ".widget.SearchWidgetBroadcastReceiver"), 
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    startAlarm(context, UPDATE_RATE_SEC);
}
```

so in the code above `startAlarm()` is never executed since `pm.setComponentEnabledSetting()` throws the SecurityException

Am I missing any security settings in my manifest? Currently I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I'm developing for `SDK v. 1.5` and it used to work fine

P.S. It happens on the phone and the emulator

Comment: Is that behaviour restricted to particular OS versions of the emulator?

Comment: I'm not running emulator - this is directly on the phone. Latest SDK, Eclipse plugin, Java 6 on Windows XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - this is not really answer but rather a workaround. If someone wants to step in and provide answer or explanations on how this should be done I would gladly accept that.
Anyway - I got it working by changing `newState` flag from `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED` to `PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT`. Since my broadcast receiver has enabled state in the manifest it works just fine

Answer (score 3):

At the manifest.xml you will add

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/>
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

At the Android.mk   will add

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
```

this is all.

Comment: How its work. Here in my application always give crash when I am doing disable application. Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=32495, uid=10472, package uid=10091

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding this permission in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/>
```

Comment: This would only work for a system app, otherwise this permission would be denied.

Answer (score 0):

I only got this error "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: " when I try to disable some component out of the package it is running in.Otherwise, I got success.