# Enable BroadcastReceiver of other application using PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, securityexception, android-package-managers

I want to start the BroadcastReceiver of other application installed on my android device from my app. Here is the code

```
ComponentName componentName  = new ComponentName("com.example.myapp","com.example.myapp.MyBroadcastReceiver");
pkgManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                         PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                         PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

"com.example.myapp" is the package name of the other application which contains "MyBroadcastReceiver"

I referred answers given in the post [Android PackageManager enable any application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445881/android-packagemanager-enable-any-application) and [Android - can't enable BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052589/android-cant-enable-broadcastreceiver) but none of them seems to be working. The application continues throwing the permission denial SecurityException. Given is the logcat

```
05-24 11:37:38.382: E/AndroidRuntime(8746): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=8746, uid=10042, package uid=10041
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void setComponentEnabledSetting(ComponentName componentName,  
            int newState, int flags) {  
        setEnabledSetting(componentName.getPackageName(),  
                componentName.getClassName(), newState, flags);  
    }  

public void setApplicationEnabledSetting(String appPackageName,  
            int newState, int flags) {  
        setEnabledSetting(appPackageName, null, newState, flags);  
    }  



private void setEnabledSetting(  
            final String packageName, String className, int newState, final int flags) {  
        if (!(newState == COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT  
              || newState == COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED  
              || newState == COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED)) {  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid new component state: "  
                    + newState);  
        }  
        PackageSetting pkgSetting;  
        final int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();  
        final int permission = mContext.checkCallingPermission(  
                android.Manifest.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE);  
        final boolean allowedByPermission = (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);  
        boolean sendNow = false;  
        boolean isApp = (className == null);  
        String componentName = isApp ? packageName : className;  
        int packageUid = -1;  
        ArrayList<String> components;  
        synchronized (mPackages) {  
            pkgSetting = mSettings.mPackages.get(packageName);  
            if (pkgSetting == null) {  
                if (className == null) {  
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(  
                            "Unknown package: " + packageName);  
                }  
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(  
                        "Unknown component: " + packageName  
                        + "/" + className);  
            }  
            if (!allowedByPermission && (**uid != pkgSetting.userId**)) {  
                throw new SecurityException(  
                        "Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid="  
                        + Binder.getCallingPid()  
                        + ", uid=" + uid + ", package uid=" + pkgSetting.userId);  
            }  
....  
}
```

**It will compare uid，so can't disable or enable other application.**
from: /frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java

Comment: That is from [Android source](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/services/java/com/android/server/PackageManagerService.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base&r=1ccac75e1f1b97eccb916a8de04fc1012b30f6e5&spec=svn.platform--frameworks--base.6a67a38f46cafdb9a9cedf3351f7150140cf0bd7#4668) - should have been sated clearly in the answer